# How to use an integer resource in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use an integer stored in a fikle in the values folder but something isn't woring right. Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="numb">5</integer>
</resources>
```

And here is the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("testLog", R.integer.numb+"");

}
```

But when I run it the output is:

```
04-02 14:08:30.044: D/test(14839): 2131099648
```

Why do I get get 5 instead?

Comment: `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb)`

Comment: R.integer.numb is the resource identifier (look at the generated R.java file where it is defined. If you use Android Studio try placing your cursor at R.integer.numb in your source code and press ctrl+b and see where it takes you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
int value = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb);
```

For more information check the docs under the topic **Integer**.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Quoting docs

Resources

> The Android resource system keeps track of all non-code assets
>   associated with an application. You can use this class to access your
>   application's resources. You can generally acquire the Resources
>   instance associated with your application with getResources().

`getResources()` is a method of `Context`.

Comment: Oh ok, you mean I'm calling the identifier used by the R class instead of the resource it refers to?

Comment: @spacitron yes and do check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Comment: @spacitron if interested you can further look @ the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.getInteger%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

When you are accessing values from resources you need to use getResources()  method like below,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("testLog", getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb) + "" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("testLog", getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb)+"");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in Activity:

```
int numb = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb);
```

Use in Fragment:

```
int numb = getActivity().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numb);
```